# Help in defining value function for 0/1 knapsack

Tags: algorithms

I would like to set up some type of automation/suggestion tool for buying items on a limited spending budget. To try to somewhat formalise the problem, one could suggest to reduce this to a 0/1 knapsack problem with item *i* having price $p_i$ and value $v_i$ and then finding a set of items that maximise the total value, respecting $\sum_{i \in I} p_i \leq b $, where b is my budget.

However, I would need to define a value function *F* mapping from the set of items to say integers. I could potentialy define this function as a weighted linear sum, where there are some properties that I care about and weigh the property accordingly. Are there better approaches or functions for this issue of mine?

Comment: I did not understand the second paragraph. Is the weighted linear sum is over properties? Property of what? Could you please elaborate using an example, etc.

Comment: say I have items {keyboard, phone, watch} and I would like to attribute each item a value (e.g. from 0 to 100). So that the value is not pulled out my a***, I would say that value is defined as $0.3 \cdot$ importance + $\ 0.5 \cdot $ urgence + $0.2\cdot $ color. Hence to me, value is composed of importance, urgence and color, and I weigh them accordingly. Does that clarify it at least a little?

Comment: Okay. I understand a bit. Do you know the "importance", "urgence", "color" for each item? If so, simply substitute these variables and get the value $v_i$ for each item. And then apply 0-1 knapsack algorithm. How about that?

Comment: If you do not know the value of variables: "importance", "urgence", "color", defining an optimal solution is not possible. The optimal solution will change depending on the values of "importance", "urgence", "color".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding.  In the knapsack problem, there is a value for each item.  You get to define those values.

The value of a set of items is already defined.  You don't get to define it.  The value of a set of items is the sum of the values of the items in the set.  Period.  That is it.  There is no flexibility.  If you want to change that, it's not the knapsack problem any longer, it is some variant of the knapsack problem.  With the standard knapsack problem, once you have specified the value of each individual item, that fully determines the values of every possible set.

Comment: I would not like to change the values. I don't have values provided in advance, only the prices. For example, the items are {watch, keyboard, pen}, the prices are {150, 90, 10) however the value of each item would be subjective, and once they are defined, then I can formalise it as a knapsack problem. Does that make sense?

Comment: @explorer7c6, Once you have defined a value for each item, you have a knapsack problem.  If you want to approach this as a knapsack problem, you have to stick within the format of the knapsack problem itself, you can't make tweaks or do things differently no matter how more appropriate to your setting it might be.